# Increment Visits Counter from Django REST

Tags: python, django, rest

for some reason i can't figure out why my counter is only updating at first url fetch or when server is restarted (or when i just save my code and local server is updating) but not anymore after it.

Made a simple counter class

models.py

```
class HitCount(models.Model):
visits = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

And a simple update when view is supposed to be fetch from react

views.py

```
class HitCountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
HitCount.objects.filter(pk=1).update(visits=F('visits') + 1)

queryset = HitCount.objects.all()
serializer_class = HitCountSerializer
```

Also, in case of, there's my serializer.py

```
class HitCountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = HitCount
    fields = ('visits',)
```

My goal is simply to update the counter when I fetch the url then get the count data for show purposes.

Comment: On which viewset action you need to update the count?

Comment: I was simply needing to update the counter when a specific url is hit (e.g /hitcount/id/) but since i'm using serializers I didn't know how to work with, especially because i'm discovering django at the same time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class HitCountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = HitCount.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HitCountSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        HitCount.objects.filter(pk=instance.id).update(visits=F('visits') + 1)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

then try to ask GET - `http://your.domain_or_ip/hitcount/hitcount_id/`

code in position like `queryset = HitCount.objects.all()` will be only called once when init.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Had to modify it a bit to make it work (was having Response is not defined at first, since I don't have/know to import it lol) !
I went with 

    ```from django.http import JsonResponse```
and edited last line to

    ```return JsonResponse(serializer.data)```

Comment: my mistake, `from rest_framework.response import Response`

Comment: `(visits=F('visits') + 1)` you've this code in your answer i'm wondering why F what it does can you explain please?

Comment: django F expression [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions).